# Getting a database to 1NF or 2NF - mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization, database-schema

How do I get this mysql database in better 1NF or 2NF form?

[image]

I tried my best to remove redundant data. It appears there is redundant data still in "Prof_Dept"

Comment: I don't trust any file hosting that doesn't expose the file name.  Even that isn't reliable.  If you want help, post pertinent information in the question.

Comment: This is actually not homework, its a project I'm trying to work on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The schema looks strange. How can a Department by a child of Professor_Dept (with the Professor_DeptID FK in it)?  That means there is no "Science faculty".  You would be storing

```
professor john's science department
professor john's physics department
professor tom's physics department
etc
```

I think the tables should be

```
Professor
Department
   <bridge between the two> (Professor_Dept)
Course
   (this hangs off the bridge table, since the combination
    defines the Course instructor [professor] and department)
```

---

```
Professor: id, name, e.g. "John"
Department: id, name, e.g. "COM"
Professor_Dept: id, professor_id (FK), department_id (FK), modified_date
Course: Professor_Dept_id (FK), number, course_modified
```

From a course, you already know through the FK which professor and dept it relates to.

Comment: So you're saying (4) tables: Professor, Dept, Prof_Dept, and Course?

Comment: @Richard - I originally had this, but then realized the redundancy once i inputted dummy data for the course table for example: Course: COM 310 then for a second record **COM** 420, etc. The COM part was repeated over and over. Anyway to get rid of this? That was part of my reasoning for putting DeptName in a seperate table (e.g. COM part).

Comment: @Richard - this would violate 2NF if you have COM, COM, COM repeatedly listed again and again throughout the database: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: @woopie table structure added

Comment: My question is, can it create problems to consistently have com called repeately in the same table?

Comment: @woopie I don't understand your question. How does your schema not store COM multiple times? COM (dept name) would only be stored in the dept table